how to access object outside dart file using getx
i want to access cameras in another dart file, how can i do it, my app is complex can't be shared through constructor, i am using Getx (i am new to getx), help is appriciated
this is my main.dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


In this case, using a service locator seems to be a proper solution. A good candidate would be get_it.
Setup:
After installing it in your project:
flutter pub add get_it

You could declare a global instance of it:
GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

The recommendation for registering classes is to have an abstraction layer. Example:
class Camera {
  // ...
}

abstract class CamerHandler {
  List<Camera> getAvailableCameras();
}

class CameraHandlerImplementation implements CamerHandler {
  @override
  List<Camera> getAvailableCameras() {
    // ...
  }
}

Note that you can also register concrete types. The recommendation for using the abstract base classes as a registration type is to vary the implementations.
Therefore, you could register it as:
getIt.registerSingleton<CamerHandler>(CameraHandlerImplementation());

Make sure to register your class(s) when launching - in the main before calling runApp(const MyApp());
Usage:
Now, you have access to it throughout your whole app's scope!
final cameras = getIt<CamerHandler>().getAvailableCameras();

You might want to look at the different methods for registering for your class; registerSingleton should be suitable here...

It's a local variable, but you can declare it globally and make a getter function for it:
var cameras;

void main(){
 // initialize cameras here
} 

getCameras()=>cameras;

You can call getCameras() or cameras itself  anywhere to get the value of that variable.

There is no need to make a getter for it since it's public (not _cameras). Also, let's keep in mind that it has to be the await availableCameras().

@AhmedF, mainly global variable is discouraged but it's the easiest way until now. it's ok to access it by name since it's not private to its file but it sense of formalization to have a getter. and main method is async so he can await.
